# Need to split #tags to text

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I Need to split #tags to meaningful words in an automated way.

**Sample Input:**

- iloveusa
- mycrushlike
- mydadhero

**Sample Output**

- i love usa
- my crush like
- my dad hero

Any utility or open API that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split words on boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781936/split-words-on-boundary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check - [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) from [Norvig](http://norvig.com/)'s work.

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Counter
import re, nltk

WORDS = nltk.corpus.brown.words()
COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)

def pdist(counter):
    "Make a probability distribution, given evidence from a Counter."
    N = sum(counter.values())
    return lambda x: counter[x]/N

P = pdist(COUNTS)

def Pwords(words):
    "Probability of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return product(P(w) for w in words)

def product(nums):
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for x in nums:
        result *= x
    return result

def splits(text, start=0, L=20):
    "Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), L)+1)]

def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest) 
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

print segment('iloveusa')     # ['i', 'love', 'us', 'a']
print segment('mycrushlike')  # ['my', 'crush', 'like']
print segment('mydadhero')    # ['my', 'dad', 'hero']
```

For better solution than this you can use bigram/trigram.

More examples at : [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb)