# Split words on boundary

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have some tweets which I wish to split into words. Most of it works fine except when people combine words like: `trumpisamoron` or `makeamericagreatagain`. But then there are also things like `password` which shouldn't be split up into `pass` and `word`.

I know that the nltk package has a `punkt tokenizer` module which splits sentences up in a smart way. Is there something similar for words? Even if it isn't in the nltk package?

Note: The example of `password -> pass + word` is much less of a problem than the splitting word problem.

Comment: if you're working with `#hashtags`, they should be treated differently (but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: not that this is of any help, but you could get a text file of all the words in English and compare the tweets to the words. Far from 100% accurate, though.

Comment: This would be the absolute brute-force solution (and would take significant computing power, likely), but you could take the phrase `trumpisamoron` and run all possible permutations of words in that string and compare each word's likelihood of occurrence versus a dictionary of `word: frequency` key-value pairs. This basically means you would test which of `t`, `tr`, `tru`, `trum`, or `trump` is more likely to be a word. I would not recommend this solution, but depending on the size of your data, it might be doable.

Comment: @not_a_robot I thought of that except I have things like narcisticidiots. So then it becomes tough because then you need to deal with, should I stop at narcist, or narcistic. Same with idiot vs idiots.

Answer (score 1):

Ref : My Answer on another Question - [Need to split #tags to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621703/need-to-split-tags-to-text/38624458#38624458).

Changes in this answer I made are - (1) Different corpus to get `WORDS` and (2) Added `def memo(f)` to speed up process. You may need to add/use corpus depending upon Domain you are working on.

Check - [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) from [Norvig](http://norvig.com/)'s work.

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Counter
import re, nltk
from datetime import datetime

WORDS = nltk.corpus.reuters.words() + nltk.corpus.words.words()
COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)

def memo(f):
    "Memoize function f, whose args must all be hashable."
    cache = {}
    def fmemo(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    fmemo.cache = cache
    return fmemo

def pdist(counter):
    "Make a probability distribution, given evidence from a Counter."
    N = sum(counter.values())
    return lambda x: counter[x]/N

P = pdist(COUNTS)

def Pwords(words):
    "Probability of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return product(P(w) for w in words)

def product(nums):
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for x in nums:
        result *= x
    return result

def splits(text, start=0, L=20):
    "Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), L)+1)]

@memo
def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest) 
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

print segment('password')     # ['password']
print segment('makeamericagreatagain')     # ['make', 'america', 'great', 'again']
print segment('trumpisamoron')     # ['trump', 'is', 'a', 'moron']
print segment('narcisticidiots')     # ['narcistic', 'idiot', 's']
```

Sometimes, in case, word gets spilt into smaller token, there may be higher chances that word is not present in our `WORDS` Dictionary.

Here in last segment, it broke `narcisticidiots` into 3 tokens because token `idiots` was not there in our `WORDS`.

```
# Check for sample word 'idiots'
if 'idiots' in WORDS:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

You can add new user defined words to `WORDS`.

```
.
.
user_words = []
user_words.append('idiots')

WORDS+=user_words
COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)
.
.
.
print segment('narcisticidiots')     # ['narcistic', 'idiots']
```

For better solution than this you can use bigram/trigram.

More examples at : [Word Segmentation Task](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb)